# from Kotlin to Java

Tags: java

I am working on the problem. Could you please help me out and show how the below piece of code look like in Java.

```kotlin
(0 until n).forEach { i ->
     var itis = sc.nextInt() - 1
     allData[itis]!!.add(i)

     if (allData[itis]!!.size == k) {
          (0 until k).forEach { j ->
               result[j].addFirst(allData[itis]!!.poll())
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    int itis = sc.nextInt() - 1;
    if(allData[itis] != null){
        allData[itis].add(i);
        if (allData[itis].size() == k) {
            for(int j=0; j<k; j++){
                result[j].addFirst(allData[itis].poll());
            }   
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "The !! Operator
The third option is for NPE-lovers: the not-null assertion operator (!!) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if the value is null. We can write b!!, and this will return a non-null value of b (e.g., a String in our example) or throw an NPE if b is null:" - as I know !! means that you tell the compiler it won't be null, so it doesn't need to check - link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator